# Table search filter not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I  have dashboard link to list job status 
When I search few words its working fine but when I paste complete job name /enter full job name I'm not getting the result.

here is my code:

html Code:

```
 tr ng-repeat="x in person |  filter : search |pagination: curPage *
      pageSize | limitTo: pageSize"
```

Angular js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngResource','ui.bootstrap' ]);
app.filter('pagination', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    };
});
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.search = "search";
    $scope.curPage = 1;
    $scope.pageSize = 10; // items per page

    $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'PopulateTable'
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.person = data;
            $scope.numberOfPages = function() 
            {
                return Math.ceil($scope.person.length / $scope.pageSize);
            };

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
        $scope.resetFilters = function () {
            // needs to be a function or it won't trigger a $watch
            $scope.search = {};
        };

        // pagination controls

        $scope.totalItems = $scope.person.length;

        // $watch search to update pagination
        $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.filtered = filterFilter(1000, newVal);
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
            $scope.curPage = 1;
        }, true);

    };
    // create empty search model (object) to trigger $watch on update

};
```

Can any one help me with this. 
TIA

Comment: Create a **runnable** demo that reproduces problem

Comment: @dileepvarma i suggest you use some components like [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) or [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/) to filter and sort your data-tables